# What word describes the process of conceptualizing a collection of things by giving it a name?

Tags: vocabulary

Around 1999, a woman told me about this sort of meta-verb (in English) which I found so magical. I've been searching for this word again but can't find it.

As an example, I could say "Look, I attached these three short wooden rods to the bottom of this flat circle of wood. I can place it so that the rods are against the floor and then rest my bottom against the circle of wood, thereby elevating me above the floor. How nice." But if instead I say, "I made a stool," I've taken that whole idea and expressed it in one word, and this word carries meaning even beyond the one stool I just made. If there were no such word, stool, this concept of wood-assisted buttocks elevation would never congeal in the same way.

What is the word for this thing that happens when a word for something is created or discovered?

*Edit:*  I really appreciate all of these awesome words you all have shared. I've been studying the meanings of  neologism  and reify.  And I think what I'm basically looking for  is neologistic  reification. Does anyone know of a single word synonym  for something like neologistic  reification?

Comment: I know what you mean, but cannot think of a word. Perhaps someone needs to create the very word that describes the process of word-creation.  I am not sure that I support your optimism for such a practice however. It is all very well with something animate, like a stool. But the problem when you name an abstract idea, is that the name can take on a life of its own. Words such as 'evolution', 'socialist', 'atheist', 'liberal' are all immensely powerful words from the 19th century, but all can mean almost anything anyone decides for the moment they want them to mean.

Comment: I'm not looking to create a word. There already is a word. I knew the word about 14 years ago. But I haven't been able to remember it  for about 12 years. The woman who taught be about it learned it from a college professor of hers, and it stuck with her.

Comment: Do you mean _reify_  tr.v. ...
To regard or treat (an abstraction) as if it had concrete or material existence? ... concretise? ... externalise? ...objectivise?

Comment: reify - That's extremely close (in meaning I mean). If I could duct tape reify to neologism and stick them in a blender, that would be the word I remember.

Comment: Asking the community to come up with the specific word you've forgotten while dismissing every other potential candidates is a bit frustrating. I understand you're in search of that special forgotten word, but the phenomenon you're describing isn't all that complicated. "When a word for something is created or discovered," that something is *named,* or perhaps *classified.* There are plenty of synonyms for those two verbs, and some time spent with a thesaurus will hopefully lead you to the one you're looking for.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: I apologize for the frustration. I know it's annoying. I've been coming back to this question periodically for several years now. I keep hoping that as the internet matures some reverse dictionary look-up or thesaurus will be able to point me to the word. Though I haven't found that word again yet, I am really enjoying the study of many of these words that were previously unknown to me. This search certainly has not been fruitless for me. I appreciate all of the contributions.

Comment: The words **incarnation** , **incarnate** are usually reserved for the special case of Jesus' taking on human 'flesh' (ie becoming a man) (whilst continuing to be part of the Godhead). As one of Jesus' titles is 'the Word', and 'God speaks and it is created', there is an obvious tie-in (but don't expect _anyone_ to be able to _fully_ explain the actualities involved or even the semantics). There is nothing blasphemous about using 'incarnation' for 'fleshing out' in less holy circumstances, though.

Answer (score 2):

Neologism, coining a new word. This can also be used as a noun.

Comment: Um. You just said that a noun can also be used as a noun.

Comment: Whoops. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The word I'm looking for more specifically describes the birth of concept. There is a phrase used in computer science that is similar - hierarchical abstraction, the ability to work with broad functional ideas, without having to consider the minutia of the functions and processes that are being leverage for your current use. Encapsulation is the process of bundling areas of code under a single class or function name, and it gives rise to hierarchical abstraction. Neologism is like encapsulation. I'm looking for something more like hierarchical abstraction...

Comment: Then it is time to create a new word. To the etymologies! I'll be back with a new, valid word formulated through English roots.

Comment: Even Geoff Pullum doesn't have the power to impose new words.

Comment: Oh yes. The noun for Neologism is a word that hasn't been accepted as an actual word yet.

Comment: And is thus off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is the epistemological process of concept-formation called ***integration***. To *integrate* means to render something whole. Mental integration is the cardinal function of man's consciousness - integration of sense data into percepts followed by the conscious integration of percepts into concepts (*stool* in your example).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities:

- to sublimate
- to hypostatize

Comment: Why sublimate? It already has meanings.

Comment: @WS2, I think you misunderstood the original question.

Comment: hypostatize is another very closely related word, and a really awesome word, I must add. Thank you.